# Arduino error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of 'LinkedListItem' with no type

Tags: c++, arduino

I'm getting an error while attempting to write a program for an Arduino.  I'm a novice at C++ so this very well could be something simple and obvious that I am missing.  I am attempting to create a simple templated linked list but keep running into issues.  I have the following declared within its own ino file in my sketchbook.  When I attempt to use the LinkedListItem class, I get the following error.  Even if I remove the templating, I still get the same error.

```
error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of 'LinkedListItem' with no type
LinkedList:9: error: expected ';' before '<' token
```

And the code:

```
template <class T>
class LinkedListItem {

  public:
    LinkedListItem(T value);
    T getValue();
    LinkedListItem<T>* getPreviousItem();
    void setPrevious(LinkedListItem<T>* previous);
    LinkedListItem<T>* getNextItem();
    void setNext(LinkedListItem<T>* next);

  private:
    LinkedListItem<T>* _previous;
    LinkedListItem<T>* _next;
    T _value;
};

template <class T>
LinkedListItem<T>::LinkedListItem(T value) {
  _value = value;
}

template <class T>
T LinkedListItem<T>::getValue() {
  return _value;
}

template <class T>
LinkedListItem<T>* LinkedListItem<T>::getPreviousItem() {
  return _previous;
}

template <class T>
void LinkedListItem<T>::setPrevious(LinkedListItem<T>* previous) {
  _previous = previous;
}

template <class T>
LinkedListItem<T>* LinkedListItem<T>::getNextItem() {
  return _next;
}

template <class T>
void LinkedListItem<T>::setNext(LinkedListItem<T>* next) {
  _next = next;
}
```

I am declaring a pointer to a LinkedListItem like this:

```
LinkedListItem<String>* _list;
```

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: You don't need to provide template arguments in `LinkedListItem<T>` inside the class.

Comment: Is the template parameter `std::string` ? If that is the case, `s` should be lower case.

Comment: Not to interrupt your studies, but std::forward_list does exist too, if you just need a generic list

Comment: I cleaned up the class definition removing the template arguments and still no luck.

Comment: So update your post with what you have now that still doesn't work.  And put some indication in your code as to where "line 9" is that gives the compiler error.

Comment: You seem not to have selected an answer for your question. What is missing still? What more can we do for you?

Answer (score 1):

You probably meant "string" instead of "String" from std. After that change, it compiles. See the working code below.

```
#include <string>

using namespace std;

template <class T>
class LinkedListItem {

  public:
    LinkedListItem(T value);
    T getValue();
    LinkedListItem<T>* getPreviousItem();
    void setPrevious(LinkedListItem<T>* previous);
    LinkedListItem<T>* getNextItem();
    void setNext(LinkedListItem<T>* next);

  private:
    LinkedListItem<T>* _previous;
    LinkedListItem<T>* _next;
    T _value;
};

template <class T>
LinkedListItem<T>::LinkedListItem(T value) {
  _value = value;
}

template <class T>
T LinkedListItem<T>::getValue() {
  return _value;
}

template <class T>
LinkedListItem<T>* LinkedListItem<T>::getPreviousItem() {
  return _previous;
}

template <class T>
void LinkedListItem<T>::setPrevious(LinkedListItem<T>* previous) {
  _previous = previous;
}

template <class T>
LinkedListItem<T>* LinkedListItem<T>::getNextItem() {
  return _next;
}

template <class T>
void LinkedListItem<T>::setNext(LinkedListItem<T>* next) {
  _next = next;
}

int main()
{
    LinkedListItem<string>* _list;
    return 0;
}
```

Also, this is not a typical to implement linked list. Besides, you could just use the corresponding linked list from std unless you have a specific requirement you have not yet mentioned.

Comment: I'm working on an arduino board which has a considerably stripped down set of libraries.  The IDE includes a custom string library named String.  The std::string and std::forward_list classes are not available as far as I know.  If they are, I would gladly use them.

Comment: @Jasonf: So, have my post helped? Have you included your String class in the beginning of the file? If it is in a namespace, you need to use that, too.

Comment: Sorry, that did not work.  I also tried `LinkedListItem<int> test;` which gave me the same error.

Comment: @jasonf: Which compiler are you using on which host OS? Has my code worked for you if you build on desktop?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure what actually solved my problem, but I ended up moving my LinkedList class into its own header file that goes in the Arduino/libraries directory.  I had the class declaration and implementation split into separate .h and .cpp files, but that required me to include both files to get my code working.  So, I put them back together into one .h file.  I modeled my class after the QueueList library http://playground.arduino.cc/Code/QueueList.

For anyone facing a similar issue on Arduino, I recommend creating your own library.  See http://arduino.cc/en/Hacking/LibraryTutorial for more information.  As mentioned above, I could not get my code to work when split into separate .h and .cpp files unless I included both the .h and the .cpp files.